# Reload property file in Mule without restarting server

Tags: quartz-scheduler, mule

I have been struggling in this issue to reload a  property file in a mule application.
       My requirement is I am reading cron expression from a property file inside mule-config.xml. if i update cron expression without restart a server then it is not taking updated one still taking old one. I am using Quartz schedular for this purpose.Could you please help me.  Thanx in advance.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406748/mule-3-3-auto-reload-properties

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your mule-config.xml ... do some changes (Like adding a comment etc ... which will not affect the flows) then save it... If your application is running on mule standalone server , open the mule-config.xml with any editor and do the same as mentioned above and save it ... Mule will automatically reload the property file without restarting the server .... hope this help